# How to make the 'find' command in Pop OS launcher to search through the files in a disk partition?

Tags: find, partition, pop-os, launcher

I have a disk partition by the name 'other_jazz' at the location `/media/sam/other_jazz`. The `find` command in the Pop OS launcher doesn't search through the files inside the 'other_jazz' partition.

I've already enabled auto-mount on system startup for the 'other_jazz' partition.

How do I make the `find` command in the Pop OS launcher to search through data inside this partition?

Comment: Have you confirmed it's mounted at the time you issue the command? How exactly have you "enabled auto-mount on system startup"? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you verify that the `find` works from the command line? I assume the Pop launcher is a GUI interface: is there a debug option that can reveal the actual command it is issuing ?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, I've confirmed. The partition in question is mounted at all times. I've enabled it by adding the uuid of the partition in the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: When asked to provide more information please do so by [edit]ing the question. Do not reply in comments.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Yes `find` is working as expected from command-line. Are you implying that the `find` command in Pop OS application-launcher is nothing but an implementation of the linux `find` command?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I request you to re-read the original question again for better comprehension. I've explicitly mentioned that the partition is auto-mounted on system startup. I don't see adding 'how' I did it will add any real value to the original question.

Comment: @Archit  My bad -- I assumed a Launcher in a Linux-based distro would leverage Linux utilities, rather than reinvent (apparently badly) the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

Why your `find`-command doesn't include a certain directory is open to speculation. One possible reasion might be that the `-xdev`-option is set, which prevents `find` from traversing file system boundaries.

That means: suppose you have the following layout:

```
/dev/hd1 mounted on /
/dev/hd2 mounted on /usr
```

Then this command:

```
find / -name "ls" -print
```

will find `/usr/bin/ls` but this:

```
find / -xdev -name "ls" -print
```

will not.

Comment: I referred to the `find` command that is available inside the default application-launcher in Pop OS and not the popular `find` Linux terminal command.

Comment: @Archit: I did understand that. I suppose - yes, i could have made that clearer - the default application-launcher is based upon the find-command as well and might have this option set. I admit there are many other possible reasons, but to thoroughly investigate the case there is simply not enough data provided,. My spculation was offered in the hope it might help you analyse your problem better.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if the `-xdev` option is set or not?

Comment: @Archit  You could run the Launcher under `strace`, and search the resultant (huge) log for any child processes that look find-ish. That assumes you can discover how to run Launcher from the command-line, so it can be a child of strace.